# I need to storage different objects in the same class in Parse(coding: Swift)

Tags: swift, object, parse-platform

1. I want to storage all my `QuizObject[i].Question/Answers[j]/Answer`
   where `i=0,10 j=0,3` in the same Parse class as different objects with
   different id`s:

   ```
   var object=PFObject(className:"Quiz3")  
   object.addObject(QuizObject[0].Question, forKey: "Question1")
   object.addObject(QuizObject[0].Answers[0], forKey: "Answer1")
   object.addObject(QuizObject[0].Answers[1], forKey: "Answer2")
   object.addObject(QuizObject[0].Answers[2], forKey: "Answer3")
   object.addObject(QuizObject[0].Answers[3], forKey: "Answer4")
   object.addObject(QuizObject[0].Answer, forKey:"CorrectAnswer")
   object.pinInBackground()
   object.saveEventually()
   ```
2. I mean i want in the same class to have one row for each object but
   the `forKeys` to be the same. How could I do this?

Comment: you could just append all the questions to an array, and all the answers to an array, and make sure your keys used to store the questions and answers are used to store arrays. That way one row, can contain a variable amount of questions and answers without defining fields for each separate one

Comment: thank you, interesting idea, didn't think of it, I will try it. I also want to understand the solution for the direction I had as it is kind of sitting on my nerve